# Настройка высоты для View

Tags: android

Необходимо составить таблицу погоды. Для этого использую такую конструкцию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что TextView все заполняются моментально и на сколько я понимаю под них выстраивается высота всего GridView. Затем через несколько секунд подгружаются картинки и они добавляются в таблицу. Но GridView вместо того, чтобы увеличить свою высоту - размеров не изменяет, в итоге его половина запрятана внизу. Ее можно пролистнуть и увидеть, но все же хотелось чтобы GridView растянулся по высоте содержимого. Я так и указал: layout_height = "wrap_content" и не понимаю почему это не срабатывает.

[image: Слева до подгрузки картинки, справа - после]

Вот еще скриншот. Слева до подгрузки картинки, справа - после.
Скажите пожалуйста как это исправить?

Явно устанавливать размер картинки не хотелось бы, как по мне это криво, я не знаю заранее какой размер она будет занимать. Устанавливать высоту GridView match_parent тоже не хотелось бы т.к. это вытеснит будущие нижние View за экран.

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_forecast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"
        android:numColumns="5">
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tu">
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_temp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="25">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_humidity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="80%">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: разметку добавьте, минимально необходимую

Comment: @iamtihonov, добавил

Answer (score 0):

если вы можете узнать когда изображения подгрузились то после их загрузки выполните этот код:

```
int rh=imageView.getHeight();
int h=gridView.getHeight()+rh;
gridView.setHeight(h);
```